# HTML/CSS/JS Popup video cannot display more than 1

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Im working on a school project website and i wanted to have video's as a popup from a button so i did that but it only works with one video, e.g. i press the button for the first video and i get the video, then the second video (with different source in html) i get the video from the first button.

```js
window.document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = event;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    lightbox_close();
  }
}

function lightbox_open(src) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  document.getElementById("vid").innerHtml = '<source src="' + src + '"></source>';
  document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("vid").play();
}

function lightbox_close() {
  document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("vid").pause();
}
```

```css
#fade {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2000;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  animation-name: opacity;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  opacity: .85;
}

#light {
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 360px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: -180px;
  z-index: 2001;
  overflow: visible;
}

#boxclose {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #222222;
  border: 1px solid slategray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: slategray;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 11px 3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 2003;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#boxclose:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.045, 1.045);
}

.boxclose:before {
  content: "×";
}

#fade:hover~#boxclose {
  display: none;
}

#vid {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px slategray, 0px 0px 5px slategray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: slategray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px #777;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #8c97a1;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 3px #555;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<div id="light">
  <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="lightbox_close();"></a>
  <video id="a" width="600" itemtype="2" controls>
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
</div>
<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
<div>
  <button onclick="lightbox_open();"><big>Other Topic video</big></button>
</div>
<p>Video Button</p>
</div>
```

sorry if the code is a little messy im just focusing on functionality right now.

Comment: Where is your second video source? please post a [mcve]

Comment: One of the main issues, your `lightbox_open()` function is expecting a `src` argument but the button that is invoking the function does not providing anything.

Comment: You also have this `document.getElementById("vid").innerHtml =...` but your HTML markup does not include any element with `id="vid"` so therefore you have no element to render any video element on.
This needs some serious rework.